# Onclick Hide/Unhide in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Below is a screenshot of my Shiny app, I have created a simple `login` page to give access rights to the data only to the authenticated users. But I have the following issues,

1. Unable to hide the `Mainpanel` on the start of the app, meaning- the `mainpanel` should be `hidden` on the start of the app and should be `visible` only after `Login` button is pressed.
2. After the `mainpanel` is `visible`  the `sidebar` where the `Username`, `Password` and `Login button` should be hidden.

   [image]

`UI.R`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
 useShinyjs(),
 titlePanel(
 fluidRow(  
column(9, h1("VHMS")),
column(1, img(src = '2.png', width = 100))), windowTitle = "my"),

br(),
br(),
br(),
br(),
sidebarLayout(

sidebarPanel(
             textInput("Username", "Username"),
             passwordInput("Password", "Password"),
             actionButton("Login", "Login")),position = "right",


mainPanel(

  fluidRow( column(12,

 (tabsetPanel("views", type = "tabs",
                 tabPanel("TableView", dataTableOutput("df_directions")),
                 tabPanel("MapView", dataTableOutput("df_locations"))
  )


  )
  )
  )         
  ) 
  )
  )
 )
```

`Server.R`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
useShinyjs()
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
output$df_directions <-   renderDataTable({
json_data1 }, options = list(scrollX = TRUE))  
})
```

I'am able to address my issues individually but I am not able to integrate my `Hide/Show` login into a single script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your code modified to hide the main panel until the user make click on "Login". It still needs to validate the username and password.

```R
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  titlePanel(
    fluidRow(  
      column(9, h1("VHMS")),
      column(1, img(src = '2.png', width = 100))
    ), 
    windowTitle = "my"
  ),
  br(),
  br(),
  br(),
  br(),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel( id = "loginID",
             textInput("Username", "Username"),
             passwordInput("Password", "Password"),
             actionButton("Login", "Login")
    ),
    position = "right",
    shinyjs::hidden(
      mainPanel( id = "panelID",
        fluidRow( 
          column(12,
            tabsetPanel("views", type = "tabs",
                       tabPanel("TableView", dataTableOutput("df_directions")),
                       tabPanel("MapView", dataTableOutput("df_locations"))
            )
          )
        )         
      ) 
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$df_directions <- renderDataTable(
    mtcars, 
    options = list(scrollX = TRUE)
  )  

  observeEvent(input$Login, {
    # TODO: verify username and password
    shinyjs::hide("loginID")
    shinyjs::show("panelID")
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Worked, Thanks a lot